# problem with a 3d model on three js and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

[full component three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J49T8.jpg)

```
VM90:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:344:17)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:239:11)
    at three.module.js:43638:38
```

Hi devs! the problmes in console is this one ... I know is for the path vut know i got the model in public field and still it dosen't work. I dont know why the model work well in vanilla JS.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfXrc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdyuk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztm0t.png)

Comment: Make sure you are serving the page via a webserver of some kind

Comment: Post code as plain text with code format, not a screenshot

Comment: It's donde the public was inside of src not put in the project

Answer (score 0):

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77895150/unexpected-token-doctype-is-not-valid-json-in-three-js#comment137325021_77895150) - you probably have the wrong path to the .gltf or .glb model and are getting an error page rather than the model.